# Getting text input in html and transferring to javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I understand how to use input into html to call javascript defined in the same directory as the html ex:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="someFunc(500)" >
```

so if the button is clicked the java script will run someFunc(500), is there a way to take text input, and when a button is pressed use this input as a parameter value for the java script? I know this won't work and I'm not even defining a button, but something like

```
<input type="text" id= "example" onclick="someFunc(this.value)">
```

where example is the data that was put into the input text field?

Comment: `someFunc(this.value)` ?

Answer (score 3):

What about using a listener?

```
var example = document.getElementById("example");
example.onclick = function(){
    someFunc(example.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jQuery: See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/briankueck/qvz5vzwh/)

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="example" value="12345">
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#example').on('click',function() {
    console.log($(this).val()); // 12345
});
```

The HTML 5 Recommended way, is to use data-* attributes. Like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="example2" data-product-id="my-product-1"></div>
<button id="getProductId">Get Product Id</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#getProductId').on('click',function() {
    console.log($('#example2').attr('data-product-id')); // my-product-1
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="application/javascript">
  function someFunc() {
    var value = document.getElementById('example').value;

    // do something with value here

    return false;
  }
</script>

<input type="text" id="example">
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="someFunc()" >
```